# RAID10 and RAID0 partitions

Tags: raid, partition, software-raid, raid10, raid0

Actually I have this kind of configuration:

- 4 HDDs and 1 SSD linked via SATA
- 1 SSD (8GB) linked via eSATA

RAID 10 of the 4 HDD partitioned as [ / ] and [ swap ]

SSD1 as [ /boot]

SSD as [swap]

---

Now for my new configuration I am thinking as something like this:

- [/boot] SSD1
- [/] md10 [ HDD1:HDD2 as RAID 0 → HDD3:HDD4 as RAID1 ]
- [/tmp, swap0] md0 [ partitions of HDD1:HDD2]
- [swap0] SSD2 (8GB via eSATA)

My initial idea was to use all the 4 HDDs as [/tmp] and [swap] but then I thought that the 2 HDDs (3 and 4) working as redundancy could create slow downs.

But setting up the 2 partitions of the 2 HDDs (1 and 2), actually working as RAID 0 of the md10, as RAID0 too, it shouldn't create bottlenecks.

Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Having your boot partition on an external drive is asking for disaster. Don't do it. Just make a primary boot partition on the root drive.

The SSD will be faster and more responsive than the RAID 10, as it sounds like this is for a workstation use rather than server.

I'd honestly do something like:

- SATA SSD - `/boot` + `/`
- RAID 10 HDD - `/home/<user>/`
- eSATA SSD - Use for a side project. More != better.